# How to fill with zeros empty or missing cells in a google-sheets pivot table?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

I have a table where if a row is missing it means the value for that row is zero.

so for

`2020-10-12` label `L2` has all `0` values for all display url.

`2020-10-12` label `L3` has all `0` values for all display url except d2.

[image]

How can I fill this missing data in the pivot table?

I want the graph to be analog and not discreet for each series.

[image]

My unsuccessful try:

[image]

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I have. Thanks. Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You can fill in with zeros the empty cells of the raw data and as a result the pivot table will contain zeros instead of empty cells.
- In the following script, select the sheet name where the raw data is located and choose the exact data range where you want to check for empty cells.
- The script will get all the values of the selected range and it will add zeros to the empty cells. You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to accomplish this operation:

  ```
  const data=range.getValues().map(row=>row.map(r=>r==''? 0:r));
  ```

---

### Solution:

Adjust `Sheet1` and `A1:I20` to your particular case:

```
function myFunction() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // select the name of the Sheet
  const cords = 'A1:I20'; // select the range you want to paste zeros
  const range = sh.getRange(cords);
  const data=range.getValues().map(row=>row.map(r=>r==''? 0:r)); 
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: You code added zeros. How these zero be added automatically. Without running the script manually or at least only once?

Comment: @EladBenda thanks for the feedback. Can you please clarify on the `automatically`? There are a couple of triggers you can use. For example, run a function when you edit something, or when you open something, or when you select something. A popular trigger is the time-driven trigger. You can schedule a function to run at particular time/s so you don't have to execute it manually. You can also use a custom button in the sheet itself to press it and execute that function so you don't need to go to the script editor. Ideally this could be the topic of a new question, but I can try to help you :)

Comment: Thanks, Triggers where what i looked for. Now my problem remains for columns in the pivot table that don't have a row in the raw table.

Comment: @EladBenda if a column does not have a row in the pivot table there is no way pivot table will show  something that does not exist.

Comment: So this won't work? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySSKs.png Then how would you suggest  to add missing rows artificially ?

Comment: I suggest you can copy the values of the pivot table to a new sheet. Use the script of my solution to fill the empty cells with zeros and you will be fine. Maybe you need a script to copy the values of the pivot table to a new sheet as the starting point. And then use my script as the second step. How about that ? @EladBenda

Comment: My initial intention was creating an automation for a friend to see a multi-line charts. my steps were: (1) download a raw `sheet1` from the web. (2) use an external script to enrich `sheet1` (3) create a pivot table from the enriched table (4) create and fill missing rows (5) generate a multi-line chart. How would you design this with as few user interactions as possible?